How to correctly authenticate with Autodesk Platform Services PKCE Auth Flow
During the authentication flow as described in: APS: Get 3 Legged Token PKCE, I receive the following error:
invalid_credentials: The client credentials are invalid.
I am using Rust to write my client, with the OAuth2 library and Actix-web to run an HTTP server that exposes the callback endpoint.
Client code that initiates the auth process:
let auth_url = AuthUrl::new(
            "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/authorize".to_string(),
        )
        .expect("Error parsing auth url!");

        let token_url =
            TokenUrl::new("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token".to_string())
                .expect("Error parsing token url!");

        let redirect_url = RedirectUrl::new("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/callback".to_string())
            .expect("Error parsing redirect url!");

        // Create an OAuth2 client by specifying the client ID, client secret, authorization URL and
        // token URL.
        let client = BasicClient::new(
            ClientId::new("<MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE>".to_string()),
            Some(ClientSecret::new("client_secret".to_string())),
            auth_url,
            Some(token_url),
        )
        // Set the URL the user will be redirected to after the authorization process.
        .set_redirect_uri(redirect_url);

        // Generate a PKCE challenge.
        let (pkce_challenge, pkce_verifier) = PkceCodeChallenge::new_random_sha256();

        self.pkce_verifier = Some(pkce_verifier);

        // Generate the full authorization URL.
        let (auth_url, csrf_token) = client
            .authorize_url(CsrfToken::new_random)
            // Set the desired scopes.
            .add_scope(Scope::new("data:read".to_string()))
            // Set the PKCE code challenge.
            .set_pkce_challenge(pkce_challenge)
            .add_extra_param("prompt", "login")
            .url();

        self.client = Some(client);
        self.csrf_token = Some(csrf_token);

        // This is the URL you should redirect the user to, in order to trigger the authorization
        // process.
        println!("Browse to: {}", auth_url);

After manually navigating to that url, I log in using my Autodesk credentials, and successfully receive a code back in the provided endpoint:
#[get("/api/auth/callback")]
async fn auth_callback(
    data: web::Data<Arc<Mutex<AuthManager>>>,
    query: web::Query<CallbackQuery>,
) -> impl Responder {
    if let Some(error) = &query.error {
        return HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(format!(
            "Error: {} - {}",
            error,
            query.error_description.clone().unwrap_or_default()
        ));
    }

    if let Some(code) = &query.code {
        let mut manager = data.lock().unwrap();

        let pkce = manager.get_pkce_verifier().unwrap();

        let auth_client = manager.get_client().unwrap().clone();

        println!("Received code: {}", code);
        let token_result = auth_client
            .exchange_code(AuthorizationCode::new(code.to_owned()))
            // Set the PKCE code verifier.
            .set_pkce_verifier(pkce)
            .request_async(async_http_client)
            .await;

        match token_result {
            Ok(result) => {
                result.access_token();

                HttpResponse::Ok().body("auth token received, {str_result}")
            }
            Err(err) => {
                if let ServerResponse(error) = err {
                    HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(format!(
                        "No token received due to server error response, {error}"
                    ))
                } else {
                    HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(format!("No token received, {err}"))
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        HttpResponse::BadRequest().body("No code received")
    }
}

I receive the code and print it out, as seen in the println!("Received code: {}", code); line. The error comes from the if let ServerResponse(error) = err block.
Please note, this code may be quite inefficient and not very good Rust, I am fairly new to Rust and Auth flows in general, so the purpose of this is more to find out if I am clearly doing something wrong such as:

Using the OAuth2 library incorrectly
Not providing something that Autodesk Platform Services expects
Anything else that I am clearly missing

Note: This is not a runnable example, as some types etc. were excluded for brevity. AuthManager is a simple struct that contains some values received during the first stage of authentication to be used during the callback.

I figured out the issue. It was caused by the inclusion of the client_secret parameter when constructing the OAuth2 BasicClient. From what I could find, the client secret is not required for the PKCE auth flow, as it is insecure for desktop/mobile apps etc. to store this value. The final code for constructing the client is as follows:
BasicClient::new(
            ClientId::new("<YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE>".to_string()),
            None, // This is where the client secret was
            auth_url,
            Some(token_url),
        )

The rest of the code stayed the same.
I am surprised that the inclusion of this parameter led to an "invalid credentials" error from APS. I would appreciate any comments or clarification regarding this, as I would expect it to rather just get ignored.
